# What does no shutdown command do? Cisco

Tags: cisco, cisco-commands

Newbie here. I'm studying networking and struggling to understand the no shutdown command. I don't understand what no shutdown command actually does. I've read that it enables the interface but I don't even understand what that means. What does enabling the interface do? Does it allow you to configure its settings?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the simplest sense, `shutdown` turns the interface off.
`no shutdown` turns the interface on (enables it).

You can configure an interface in either case.  Using the `shutdown` command is one of the things you can do when configuring an interface.

Answer (score 2):

The command "no shutdown" enable the interface to move from adminstration down status to UP.

Router(config)# int f0/1
Router(config)#no shutdown

The interface f0/1 status changes from adminstration down to up state .